# buck the trends -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([The Object-Oriented Thought Process by Matt Weisfeld, 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330164)):

> If, however, a manufacturer decided to install a joystick in place of the steering wheel, most drivers would balk at this, and the automobile might not be a big seller (except for some eclectic people who love **bucking the trends**). On the other hand, as long as the performance and aesthetics didn’t change, the average driver would not notice if the manufacturer changed the engine (part of the implementation) of the automobile.

How do you understand that phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ['trend'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trend) is the way things go most of the time, or the thing that people usually do. ['Buck'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buck) in this case is the verb for the violent jump that an animal may do to try to throw off a rider. ['Bucking a trend'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buck+the+trend) is an idiom that means 'doing something other than the expected'. Someone who 'love[s] bucking the trends' is one who chooses to do unusual things for the sake of being different. The author is saying that this hypothetical vehicle would only be popular among people who deliberately chose it because it is unusual.

Comment: Actually the most apropos definition of *buck* in your link is "to oppose or resist" or "to charge into (as into a headwind)" To buck a trend is to purposely resist or oppose the trend- to charge into the oncoming trend like a fish swimming upstream."